# Regular Expression filter for Meta Fields

Tags: regex

I want to parse text content to extract some parameters with Regular Expression.

My text looks like below:

```
//_META_FIELD{Parameter: S}
```

And, I want to filter content start with "`//_META_FIELD{" and end with "}`"

**So, I can get the filtered content will : Parameter: S**

Can any one help?

Comment: Which language/tool are you using for regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Regex will find what you are looking for:

#^//_META_FIELD{(.+?)}$#m

`^` is to make sure is at the beginning of the line and `$` is to make sure nothing else is after that closing `}` You can remove that if you don't need it.

Also you can see an example of that RegExp [here](http://xrg.es/#shx7j6)

Answer (score 0):

The regex should look something like this:

```
^//_META_FIELD\{(.*?)\}$
```